# A phrasal verb meaning make someone speak more

Tags: word-request, phrasal-verbs

As I asked in the title, the phrasal verb means to get sb talking, but I can't recall it, can anybody help?

Comment: Can you give us more details about who or what is causing the person to speak more and how that is being implemented?

Comment: Say, in a focus group, the coordinator should the XX the participants, something like that, or maybe the person can be put between the phrasal verb, I think it’s quite commonly seen

Comment: You might say *I'll **loosen his tongue***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- ****Draw [someone] out***: Cause someone who is reluctant to talk to open up, especially without your effort being too obvious.
- *Sound [smn] out*: Similar, but with an emphasis on getting their opinion, not merely getting them talking.
- *Prompt [smn]*: Provide an impetus or reminder for someone to start talking, perhaps even telling them what to say (like when an actor forgets a line).